# Pass in readStream to a file upload request in client-side Javascript

Tags: javascript, file-upload, request, stream, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to fetch an image and read it as a stream. Once I have the stream, I want to use this stream to upload the image to a server.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/dist/boo.jpeg')
          .then(response => response.body)
          .then( readStream => {
            fetch('http://localhost:8080/upload', {method: 'post', body: readStream});  
          });
```

or

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/dist/boo.jpeg')
          .then(response => response.body)
          .then( readStream => {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/upload', true);
            xhr.overrideMimeType('multipart/form-data');
            xhr.send(readStream);
          });
```

But the request payload that's sent is a string - `[object ReadableStream]`